# Yii pager error with light box

Tags: jquery, yii, pagination, conflict

i am using color box in TbGridView and my page consisting ajax pagination which is by default and pager which i put their with this code

```
'footer'=>CHtml::dropDownList(
            'pageSize',
            $pageSize,
            array(10=>10,25=>25,50=>50,100=>100,100000000=>'Alle'),
            array(
                'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('product-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})",
                'style'=>'width:74px'
            )
        ),
```

and a color box to open url in iframe .

my issue is when i am using pagination and pager then both are working fine when i click on link with colorbox then my pager start giving me the error giving below.

```
TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView is undefined with nlight box
```

i have tried many things but this still giving me error.
even i checked with jquery bootstrap is below jquery and i am using this jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so what would be the issue. please guide me asap. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to view the page source by right clicking on it. Check if jquery.yiigridview.js is registered or not. If not found try to register it.

Comment: its already their i tried many times via testing all scenario but its still their.

Comment: If its there then you can change 'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('product-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})", to 'onchange'=>"function(){$.fn.yiiGridView.update('product-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})}",

Comment: no i am getting new error SyntaxError: function statement requires a name 

function(){$.fn.yiiGridView.update("product-grid",{ data:{pageSize:

Comment: i change the syntax but still getting the issue once i am using colorbox then that pagesize stopped work and giving the error TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView is undefined
 

...ion() {}($.fn.yiiGridView.update("product-grid",{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() ...